# How to get the header (head line) of DataFrame in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a DataFrame variable like this:

```
julia> data
11×7 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Time │ Wind1VelX │ Wind1VelY │ Wind1VelZ │ TwrBsFxt │ TwrBsFyt │ TwrBsFzt │  
│ 1   │ 0.0  │ 25.17     │ 0.944     │ -0.1424   │ 325.4    │ -123.2   │ -6726.0  │
│ 2   │ 0.01 │ 25.62     │ 0.592     │ -0.335    │ 338.7    │ -131.0   │ -6749.0  │
│ 3   │ 0.02 │ 26.07     │ 0.24      │ -0.5275   │ 345.7    │ -141.7   │ -6754.0  │
```

I would like to know if there is a method to get the column names in an array of String like:

```
julia> header=["Time", "Wind1VelX", "Wind1VelY", "Wind1VelZ", "TwrBsFxt", "TwrBsFyt", "TwrBsFzt"]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write:

```
String.(names(data))
```

Without `String.`, like this:

```
names(data)
```

you will get a vector of `Symbol`.

Note that calling `String`, in this case, converts a single `Symbol` to `String` and by adding a dot `.` after it you broadcast it over all elements of a vector returned by `names(data)`.

Comment: Thanks Bogumil, I also wonder how to use this array to initialise an empty DataFrame ? I tried `julia> df = DataFrame(A = Int[], B = String[])` which is proposed in the documentation of Julia/DataFrame. But I didn't find a way to create an empty DataFrame by just giving the column names.

Comment: E.g. `DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [:A, :B])`. You can check out https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial for more examples.

Comment: You also need to specify the type of the columns of an empty frame if possible. Try something like DataFrame([Int, Float64, Any], [:A, :B, :C], 0)

Answer (score 2):

Get a Vector of Strings:

```
names(data)
```

Get a Vector of Symbols:

```
propertynames(data)
```